# LaTeX command with superscript and subscript

Tags: math-mode, macros

I inherited the command below from another user

```
\newcommand{\den}[2][]{%
  \mbox{$\llbracket$\bfseries #2$\rrbracket^{#1}$}%
}
```

This allows the use of `\den` with an optional superscript. As such, either `\den{word}` or `\den[1]{word}` can be used.

How can I also add an argument for subscript, so that I can either leave out all arguments or include both arguments? For example, these should all be legal:

```
\den{word}
\den[][i]{word}
\den[a][i]{word}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xparse` it's easy to add several optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for the main command
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for the brackets

\NewDocumentCommand{\den}{oom}{%
  $\llbracket
   \mbox{\bfseries#3}
   \rrbracket
   \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}
   \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}$%
}

\begin{document}

\den{word}

\den[a]{word}

\den[a][i]{word}

\den[][i]{word}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with a key-value syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for the main command
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for the brackets

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\den}{O{}m}
 {
  $
  \keys_set:nn { adamg/den } { #1 }
  \llbracket
  \mbox{\bfseries#2}
  \rrbracket
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_adamg_den_sub_tl
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NT \l_adamg_den_sup_tl { \sp{} }
    \sb{\l_adamg_den_sub_tl}
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_adamg_den_sup_tl
   {
    \sp{\l_adamg_den_sup_tl}
   }
  $
 }
\keys_define:nn { adamg/den }
 {
  sup .tl_set:N = \l_adamg_den_sup_tl,
  sub .tl_set:N = \l_adamg_den_sub_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\den{word}

\den[sup=a]{word}

\den[sup=a,sub=i]{word}

\den[sub=i]{word}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the advantage of the second one?

Comment: @Adam_G You don't care whether `sub` comes before or after `sup`, for instance. And you don't risk to forget the empty optional argument if you only want the subscript.